# How to add a value to the inside List<String> from an List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have:

```
List<List<String>> finalInfo = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I am trying to put in the index 4 a value from another list of list of strings, populated named tempInfo.

```
finalInfo.get(0).add(4, tempInfo.get(0).get(4))
```

The following error is thrown:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Thanks for your help,

Best regards.

Comment: We probably need more code, but my best bet is that the list is not modifiable. That's why you can't add anything to it.

Comment: Solved,

I had to change from:

List<List> to List<ArrayList>

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

I had to change from:

> List<List> to List<ArrayList>

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this solved your problem.

Comment: From what you told me, you cannot add a new element to List, but you can add a new element to ArayLlist. @jmizv